# Generate random number using c# and send voice call through twilio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I know how to generate a random number in C#. I read some article, How to send voice mail in Twilio. But my problem needs to send the message like this

**"Hey this is your access code 123456"**

The number 123456 will be different for different user.

How do I generate dynamic "Hey this is your access code 123456"?

Comment: var guid = Guid.NewGuid();


Joking aside; seems like you might want to do some more research before asking this question. In my opinion, this is fairly basic knowledge. (String concatination and generating a random of some kind).

Comment: This is indeed a very basic question. You really should spend some time learning the basics of C#.
Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh341490.aspx and http://www.learncs.org/ or read some C# book.
Btw the code to generate such a message: var mssage = String.Format( "Hey this is your access code {0}", new Random().Next( 100000, 1000000 ) );  (If possible always use the same instance of the random class.) Be carefully random numbers are not really random numbers!

Comment: @user2384352 Well if this is not a question about how to get such a string/message, but how to use an API, you should not add a C# tag to the question. Btw. Take a look at https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/sending-via-rest they do exactly the same. Do your homework, learn some C# basics and read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

How you do this depends on whether or not you are responding to an inbound text message or initiating a new message to send to a user.

If its the former, you can use TwiML to tell Twilio how to respond to the inbound message.  IN your case that TwiML would look like this:

```
<Response>
    <Message>Hey this is your access code [YOUR_RANDOM_NUMBER]</Message>
</Response>
```

If its the latter, you can use the Twilio C# helper library to send the message:

```
// instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
var client = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
client.SendMessage(
        "YYY-YYY-YYYY", // From number, must be an SMS-enabled Twilio number
        person.Key,     // To number, if using Sandbox see note above
        string.Format("Hey this is your access code {0}","[YOUR_RANDOM_NUMBER]")
    );
```

I'd suggest checking out our Quickstarts which will walk you through the basics of sending and receiving SMS messsages and making and receiving phone calls using C#:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/hello-monkey

Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems using in `android` app we can [auto](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview) detect `OTP` and fill text box for two factor verification. Would like to know, is it possible using `Twilio`  in wep app ? and can you answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201215/how-to-read-otp-from-mobile-website) question.