# How to Read OTP from mobile website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sms

My requirement is to listen for SMS messages from a Mobile website. The SMS will contain a OTP (One Time Password).

Technologies used in our site are ASP.Net MVC and bootstrap. This is plain mobile site and not a hybrid app.

Are there any plugins that can allow me do this? Can it be done with plain javascript?

Comment: Please explain more, are you trying to read SMS message send by third party Mobile site ?

Comment: While the customer is browsing our site using mobile. They will click on a button. Our site backend will invoke a 3rd party API. This API generates OTP that is develivered to the customer's mobile phone. The site has to read this SMS and enter it in the text box on our site. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Ok , OTP  is delivered to the customer's mobile phone. How come your site automatically read SMS which is in customers phone ? Browsers doesn't allow it. It is a security permission issue. The customer has to manually  enter received OTP in the text box on your site.

Comment: Also If API generates OTP , why not your site can get that OTP as response from API and populate in textbox ? The concept of OTP is that it should be entered manually by user. I dont know why you are doing it auto.  Check [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/08/how-to-receive-an-sms-in-node-js-with-twilio-and-hyperdev.html) post to know how your web app can receive SMS. It may help.

Comment: Thanks for the link. We don't generate the OTP. It is done by the third party for two factor authentication. That's why the API doesn't return OTP. It is delivered to the customers mobile as SMS. We need a way to read this SMS while the customer is still browsing the web site from the mobile phone.

Comment: It seems using in `android` app we can [auto](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview) detect `OTP` and fill text box for two factor verification. But I don't know wether it possible in a web app may be you can contact `Twilio` [customer care](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).

Comment: Or you could ask the user to enter  received `OTP` [manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-web-forms-app-with-sms-two-factor-authentication) in text box. If you have found any solution for web app, please post it as answer, it would help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible now in mobile browsers. Chrome release this feature in version 84 and above. With the help of WEBOTP API, we can detect OTP on the web for mobile devices.

Read Below:

Here is a Web-OTP integrated code with Angular PWA Apps: https://github.com/Rohit3230/webOtpAutoReadByAngular

Go for live working URL for angular PWA app. https://rohit3230.github.io/webOtpAutoReadByAngular/